# Output being not displayed as form data being not rendered (document.getElement)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style = "text-align:center;" id = "body">
<form id = "number" method="get" name="number">
<input type="text" id="number1" name="number1" value="" />
<input type="text" id="number2" name="number2" value="" />
</form>
<p id = "GFG_UP1" style = "font-size: 16px;">

</p>
<p id = "GFG_UP2" style = "font-size: 16px;">
</p>
<button onclick = "gfg_Run()">
Convert
</button>
<p id = "GFG_DOWN1" style = "color:red;
font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">
</p>
<p id = "GFG_DOWN2" style = "color:red;
font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">
</p>

<script>
var form = document.getElementById('number');
var el_up1 = document.getElementById("GFG_UP1");
var el_up2 = document.getElementById("GFG_UP2");
var el_down1 = document.getElementById("GFG_DOWN1");
var el_down2 = document.getElementById("GFG_DOWN2");
var array1 = form.elements.number1.value;
var array2 = form.elements.number2.value;
var numberArray1 = [];
var numberArray2 = [];
for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)
{
numberArray1[i] = "Phone" + i + ':'+array1[i];
}
el_up1.innerHTML = "Array = [" +array1+"]";;
 a = i;

for (i = 0 ; i < array2.length; i++)
{
numberArray2[i] = "Phone" + a + ':'+array2[i];
a++;
}
el_up2.innerHTML = "Array = [" +array2+"]";;
function gfg_Run(){
el_down1.innerHTML =
JSON.stringify(Object.assign(numberArray1));
el_down2.innerHTML =
JSON.stringify(Object.assign(numberArray2));
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

the following code should give output of two json arrays ["number0:34","number1:24","number2:31","number3:48"]
["number0:23","number1:43","number2:65","number3:52"]
when numbers are given input in the form but no output being shown as in the script both arrays are not able to read data by the form .
error lies in the array as if i pass directly value in array in script it runs fine
help me in debug if u can

Comment: The first issue I see is using `array1.length` instead of just `array1` because `array1` and `array2` are integers, not arrays, the way you have gotten the values out of the form.

Comment: how to make them into arrays

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a complete answer to your question, but the first thing I notice is that in your `for` loops, you're trying to use the `.length` properties of `array1` and `array2`, which aren't actually arrays:

```js
var array1 = form.elements.number1.value;
var array2 = form.elements.number2.value;
```

You're setting them to the `.value` properties of the two inputs, which are theoretically going to be digits, but taken as strings by the `.value` property, because the input type is set to "text".

So Here's what I would do instead:

```js
var form = document.getElementById('number');
var el_up1 = document.getElementById("GFG_UP1");
var el_up2 = document.getElementById("GFG_UP2");
var el_down1 = document.getElementById("GFG_DOWN1");
var el_down2 = document.getElementById("GFG_DOWN2");

/* grab the values from those text inputs, and parse them into integers (because
they will be strings because the input type is set to "text") */
var input1 = parseInt(form.elements.number1.value);
var input2= parseInt(form.elements.number2.value);
/* I also changed the names to input1 and input2 because it's confusing to have them 
labeled as 'arrays' when they're actually integers */

var numberArray1 = [];
var numberArray2 = [];

/* now just use those numerical values as your exit condition in your loops */
for (i = 0; i < input1; i++)
{
/* we're also going to use Array.push() to add vlues to the `numberarray` instead of trying to assign a value to the element at "i" */
numberArray1.push("Phone" + i + ':'+ (i+1));
}

/* I'm not 100% sure what you were trying to do here, but I'm guessing that you 
actually want to show the values 'numberArray1' here instead of the value of that 
first input, so we'll use the 'spread' operator to put that in there */
el_up1.innerHTML = `Array = [${...numberArray1}]`;
 a = i;

for (i = 0 ; i < input2; i++)
{
numberArray2.push("Phone" + a + ':'+ (i+1));
a++;
}
el_up2.innerHTML = `Array = [${...numberArray1}]`;
function gfg_Run(){
el_down1.innerHTML =
JSON.stringify(Object.assign(numberArray1));
el_down2.innerHTML =
JSON.stringify(Object.assign(numberArray2));
```